# My RestController dont return all properties from my object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I cannot serialize my complete object into a Java API Rest. Some properties are not returning in the response method.

I have a object like:

```java
public class Localization {
    private Long id;
        //another properties..
    private Person person; 
    

       // getters and setters
}
```

This is a example from my method in my RestController:

## attempt 1:

```java
@GetMapping("/getlocalization")
public ResponseEntity<Localization> getlocalization() {
  Localization localization = new Localization();
  localization.setId(1);
  localization.setPerson(
    new Person(..properties..)
  );
  return new ResponseEntity<Localization>(localization, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

## attempt 2:

```java
@GetMapping("/getlocalization")
public Localization getlocalization() {
  Localization localization = new Localization();
  localization.setId(1);
  localization.setPerson(
    new Person(..properties..)
  );
  return localization;
}
```

This is my return, without the person property:

```
{"id": 1, ..another properties...}
```

I can't get the full object like

```
{"id": 1, ..another properties..., person: {..properties..}}
```

Comment: maybe you need to add response type in the mapping, like @GetMapping("/getlocalization", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

Comment: If you are using a OneToMany relation in hibernate, check if this property doesn't have a @JsonBackReference decoration

Answer (score 0):

class localization :

```
public class Localization {
    private Long id;
    private Person person;

    //constructor with args

    // getters and setters
}
```

class Person :

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String lastName;

     //constructor with args

    // getters and setters
}
```

Your Get methode :

```
 @GetMapping("/getlocalization")
    public Localization getlocalization() {
        return new Localization(new Long(1),new Person("name","lastName"));
    }
```

it's work for me !!

Answer (score 0):

please, can you elaborate the object definitions and more elaborate on the steps you are following?

There has not been any case, where I have not received a particular property in the response after it has been sent, So it must be because of some minor mistakes which would be clear by complete lookup of classes definition.

When working with the postman Application this kind of issue comes where property name changes due to wrong naming conventions followed for setter/getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry.

I put an annotation @JsonIgnore in my property object.

@JsonIgnore
private Person person;

```java
public class Localization {
    private Long id;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Person person;

    //constructor with args

    // getters and setters
}
```

Sorry for all for the stupidity! =/